# Why isn't this get_posts() WordPress function not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use the get_posts() function in WordPress to display a list of posts  a specific category on my homepage. Here's my code:

```
<div id="announcements">

    <?php 
    $myposts = get_posts( 'category'=>3 );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    ?>

    <div id="announcement-post-title">
        <b><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to 
                    <?php the_title(); ?>" class="homepage-post-title">
        <?php the_title(); ?></a></b>
    </div>


    <div id="announcement-post-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="announcement-post-read-more">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="read-more-button">Read
                    More</a>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

When I view the page, though, I get the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /home1/mt/public_html/resources2/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/front-page.php on line 26

Line 26 is this one:

```
$myposts = get_posts( 'category'=>3 );
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to wrap `array()` around the category thing: `array('category'=>3)`

Comment: I up-voted Pekka, he is right you are storing an Array inside the variable. Your category 3 has more then one thing in it so you need an array to store those values

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "your category 3 has more than one thing in it"? Thanks!

Comment: "isn't not working"? It's working then?

Comment: ^^ I was in a rush; is there a way to edit the question title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get_posts() function expects an array to be passed.

Try:

```
$myposts = get_posts( array('category' => 3) );
```

[See the wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Comment: This isn't technically true. You can pass in a string like so:

`$myposts = get_posts( 'category=3' );`